# Performance of web application .net 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, performance, sql-server-2005

I have just started working over a website written in .net 2.0. Pages take long to load and response time is quite low, not sure where to start from in order to improve performance of the same.

Hardware is not a problem as there is enough memory and processor is also good enough.

Any Idea where should I start from and to improve the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a tool called Antz Profiler, and run your web application locally against this.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/.  This will help you identify the methods that are expensive in the application.  You can then break down the calls and try to identify whether the code is expensive or maybe DB calls.

Try and refactor and identify any code that you think could be improved, and then once this is done, move onto external calls.

If you have DB calls, then you can use SSMS to identify any issues in the query.  When you run the queries, you can use 'Include Actual Execution Plan' to show you where the bottle-necks are.

Tutorial for SSMS query optimization : http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/the-sql-server-query-optimizer/

Walkthrough for Antz: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/walkthrough

There is also a tips link here for general things to check for page speed: http://www.aspnet101.com/2010/03/50-tips-to-boost-asp-net-performance-part-i/

Also, you can use tools like **YSlow** in **Firefox** to check the http requests etc to see where you can reduce network calls.

Answer (score 2):

You start by profiling the application to find where it spends most of its time.

When you find that, you come up with an idea of how to fix the top bottleneck.

Once you tried a fix, profile again to find out if you have made a difference - if not, rollback the change and try something else.

If successful, repeat the above process.

Popular profilers are [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and [ants profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), both commercial products.

Comment: Somewhere I read:-1)set tracing to false in web.config

2)Debug="true" set it to false in comlipation tag of web config

3)Remove unwanted tags form httpmodules of machine.config

4)<pages buffer="true"> in web.config set this to false
will this help

Comment: @PranaliDesai - Those are general recommendation. It is not possible to tell from your question if these are indeed issues you are having. These are certainly starting points, but if not effective (or already in place), you need to profile.

Comment: thanks for your response let me place this general recommendations in place and then will check with profilers.